# Paging-enabled UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have tried in this event i need scroll event and also need the button click event. Here have i used multiple uiview and in that i placed button (need of both action scroll and button action) Can any one give a solution?

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
           return _scrollView;
   }
   return nil;
```

}

In this above code scroll action happening but button action not happening.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
           return nil;
   }
   return nil;
```

}

---

In this above code button action is happening,but scroll is happening for only its view and cannot able to scroll other scrollviews.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is add a scrollview apply paging in scrollview and add your Uiview inside the scrollview, suppose you have to show 5 views then try following.

```
yourScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
yourScroll.frame = CGRectMake(45, 45, 230, 300);
yourScroll.backgroundColor =   [UIColor clearColor];
yourScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(yourScroll.frame.size.width * 5, yourScroll.frame.size.height);
[yourScroll setPagingEnabled : YES];
[yourScroll setDelegate:self];

int incX = 0 ;

for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
 UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake (incX,0,yourScroll.frame.size.width,yourScroll.frame.size.height)];
//Create a button and give it the tag like    
button.tag = i;
//Now add a selector to the button and add the button to your view;
[myView addSubview:button]
[yourScroll addSubview:myView];
    incX+= 230;
}
```

and now this is your selector for scrolling with the help of button click:

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender
{
int page = [sender tag];
NSLog(@"the page is = %i",page);
CGRect frame = yourScroll.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[yourScroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have need UIview in weight 230 in center of view and right and left view show in same view in border .incX+= 320;

Comment: Edited my answer, its too simple just set the frame of the scrollview and the increement of the incX according to your use and it will work fine.